# Writing raw data to the Android Serial Port (USB)

Tags: android, android-ndk, serial-port, usb, libusb

I need to write some "raw" data to the usb port for a project of mine (no prob if root should be required).

I found a [port of libusb for Android](https://github.com/monaka/libusb-android) and managed to compile it with NDK. I linked the library to an executable of mine (executed as root), but the function "libusb_init" always returns an error (LIBUSB_ERROR_OTHER).

I found that the problem (by now...) is in the file "linux_usbfs.c", more precisely in this function:

```
static const char *find_usbfs_path(void)
{
    const char *path = "/dev/bus/usb";
    const char *ret = NULL;

    if (check_usb_vfs(path)) {
        ret = path;
    } else {
        path = "/proc/bus/usb";
        if (check_usb_vfs(path))
            ret = path;
    }

    usbi_dbg("found usbfs at %s", ret);
    return ret;
}
```

`/dev/bus/usb` obviously doesn't exist on my N1.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try pyserial? python seems simpler for me. You need either a kernel with usb host mode or your phone supports serial over a ttyMSM0 natively, which you need to find out. Once you are sure you have a serial port on your phone, look at this [link](http://karibe.co.ke/2012/07/usb-host-mode-serial-on-u8150-android-pyserial/) which is meant for huawei ideos U8150, but the pyserial stuff done using python for android is the alternative I am suggesting.